# Printing from an embedded ATMEL board

Tags: printing, embedded

We are working with an ATMEL 91 SAM board. Using this embedded system we are able to print to an HP DeskJet 1000 series j110.  The problem is we are not able to print more than one document. *I.e*, the first print job always works, but if we try to print a second time, then it won't print.  The embedded system shows that the printing is done, but the printer does not print.  Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Unlikely to get an answer for this since it lacks enough details about what your running, how you are printing etc..

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite, as marto says, the lack of information in this question, I will have a go.

If you find that you are sending sets of data to a printer and it prints out the first but then ignores subsequent sets, this would imply a problem in the termination of the first set or in the start of subsequent sets.

Are you sure that the first printout is completing correctly?  If there is some data left/corruption to the data at the end of the first print job then the printer could be left looking for this final end of data before starting the next job.  The embedded controller will send the data quite happily but the printer will just ignore it.

The same could be true for a mal-formed start  to the next job.

Look at the data being sent and manually decode it against the printer control language specification.  Not rocket science, but then driving a printer shouldn't be.